# how to call JSONObject function from oncreate function?

Tags: java, android

Don't want to make question long. Simply I want to how can i call users function inside of oncreate? Also Need i use throw catch everytime?

```
public class Json extends Activity {

    HttpClient client;
    TextView tvStatus;

    final static String url = "http://localhost/index.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.json);

        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    }

    public JSONObject users() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);

        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        tvStatus.setText(status);

        return null;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a full stacktrace?

Comment: @hexafraction sorry I'm not getting error when run code that is above. But there is error when i call function as users()

Comment: `StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);` - url will always be empty. What are you expecting the HTTPClient to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no full stacktrace yet, I will just guess. The problem is you execute the stuff on the main thread. You need to execute it in the background since Android 4.0.

There is `AsynTask` for that, you simple create a class and let it inherits. [Check this out for more infos](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I think this is not a answer for my question. There is not problem with code. I just don't know how to call users() from oncreate

Comment: How about `JSONObject jsonObect = this.users();` at the end of the function? Be aware that `jsonObject` is always null.

Comment: Can't I call setText function? I don't wanna get anything from that function for now. I think I understand something now :)